# Django admin custom CSV report

Tags: django, csv, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I have a django project with 3 models. The user, the project (in which he works on) and the Change (which logs start and finish working time as well as the project and user).

I want to export a custom CSV report. Ex: total working hours of users per project, total hours devoted to a project etc. This means that there are some calculations to be done across models before exporting. So far I have found out how to export in CSV just filtered model entries, which isn't very helpful. I also found some tools online but most of them are outdated.

Can anyone point me to a direction or give me advice or links where I can learn more? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of ways to do this. You can use [django-report-builder](https://github.com/burke-software/django-report-builder) which is a pretty neat tool.

Other ways are using custom views to admin site (check [Django AdminPlus](https://github.com/jsocol/django-adminplus)), overwrite queryset and use custom admin action etc.

Comment: I've already started with report builder after posting the question. :p Thanks very much though.